# error running full crawl in SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search, sharepoint-search, crawl

We have configured the Search Service application and while running the Full Crawl we are getting below errors.

**Error #1:** An unrecognized HTTP response was received when attempting to crawl this item. Verify whether the item can be accessed using your browser.

**Error #2:** The URL of the item could not be resolved. The repository might be unavailable, or the crawler proxy settings are not configured. To configure the crawler proxy settings, use Search Administration page.

Answer (score 0):

**Error #1:  An unrecognized HTTP response was received when attempting to crawl this item. Verify whether the item can be accessed using your browser: ***

> We had the same problem on one of our test servers which is a single
>   machine installation. In our case the machine was very slow and the
>   crawler tried to crawl too many items at once which results in a
>   timeout.
>
> So we created a crawler impact rule which defines a certain amount of
>   time the crawler waits after each requested item. Such a rule can be
>   created in the Search Settings (in the Central Administration) under
>   "Crawler Impact Rules".
>
> There you can specify the Url for which the rule should be used.
>   Furthermore you have two option to influence the crawler:
>
> Set the number of items the crawler requests at once Set the number of
>   requested item to one and define a certain amount of time, the crawler
>   waits after the request. So perhaps this might also solve your
>   problem.

[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/92186/unrecognized-http-response-in-sharepoint-search-crawl)

also refer links,

1. [An unrecognized HTTP response was received when attempting to crawl this item](https://www.danny-davis.com/blog//2016/12/sharepoint-2013-unrecognized-http.html)
2. [An unrecognized HTTP response was received when attempting to crawl this item. Verify whether the item can be accessed using your browser](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ff2f2f94-4151-4b4d-99e3-22a14c4ea2c9/an-unrecognized-http-response-was-received-when-attempting-to-crawl-this-item-verify-whether-the?forum=sharepointsearch)

**Error #2: The URL of the item could not be resolved. The repository might be unavailable, or the crawler proxy settings are not configured. To configure the crawler proxy settings, use Search Administration page.**

Refer this microsoft article to resolve this error [The URL of the item could not be resolved. The repository might be unavailable, or the crawler proxy settings are not configured.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33953.sharepoint-troubleshooting-the-url-of-the-item-could-not-be-resolved-the-repository-might-be-unavailable-or-the-crawler-proxy-settings-are-not-configured.aspx) and also refer the below links,

1. [The URL of the item could not be resolved. The repository might be unavailable](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/97448719-a4eb-4eaa-a520-dcfc01a947ec/the-url-of-the-item-could-not-be-resolved-the-repository-might-be-unavailable-or-the-crawler-proxy?forum=sharepointadmin)
2. [Sharepoint Search crawl not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/119721/sharepoint-search-crawl-not-working)